# IBM MQ server encodes messages

Tags: c#, encoding, ibm-mq

I'm sending XML to an IBM MQ Queue  that contains a CDATA section. That CDATA section contains these special characters: `$§)#ÜÖ&amp;!^`. For some reason, they are showing up within the MQ Queue as `$�)#��&amp;!^`. This causes the other send to take it off the queue with these characters and ending up having an invalid signature because the messages no longer match up.

We've verified that the message when we do a `.Put()` does contain an XML string with those special characters. I've ensured that the message has `.CharacterSet` property assigned to it that matches what we will eventually pull off the queue.

What other places can possibly be auto-encoding the special characters when it's put on the queue? Our application is in a .NET windows environment, but the MQ server is on a Linux box. Is this something to consider?

```
string xmlMsg = "<message><data><![CDATA[<value>$§)#ÜÖ&amp;!^</value>]]</data></message>"; // This is in a CDATA section.
mQMessage = new MQMessage
{
    CharacterSet = 1208,
};

mQMessage.WriteBytes(xmlMsg);

_queue.Put(mQMessage);
```

Comment: Does the message contain the bad characters right after it is put to the queue,  or when the downstream get happens?

Comment: @JoshMc If I view the message within the queue in IBM MQ Explorer, those special characters appear as `$�)#��&amp;!^`. When I am doing a `.Put()` the message I am putting on the queue has the expected characters: `$§)#ÜÖ&amp;!^`.

Comment: Can you provide sample minimal .Net code that produces this issue?  By default .Net represents things in CCSID 1200 (UTF-16).  What CCSID are you setting on the message (this will show up in your code if you can add that to the question).

Comment: Most likely, the receiving application is issuing a Get with Convert.  You have 3 options: (1) the sending application can set the MQMD.Format field to CMQC.MQFMT_NONE or (2) change the receiving application to perform the Get without Convert or (3) change the CDATA to be a HEX representation of the data.

Comment: @JoshMc Added how we are setting the `MQMessage`. @Roger I can't edit the receiving application, but the characters are converted even if I view it through MQ Explorer. The receiving application would just pull it as how it's on the queue. Also the default value is already `MQC.MQFMT_NONE` if not specified.

Comment: Have you tried to read the message with a simple utility like the sample `amqsbcg`, this will print out the HEX values of the characters in the message.  You are writing using `WriteBytes` with a Format of `MQFMT_NONE`, then the `CCSID` of the message itself would make no difference.  How it is displayed is going to depend on the character set of the displaying application.  In this case you would need to write the bytes into the message as the receive app is expecting them.

Comment: If this is not character data then there should be no need to worry about how it is displayed as long as the character values are correct.

Comment: @JoshMc How does MQ Explorer expect data to look? It shows as converted even when on the Queue.

Comment: That is why i suggest you look at the hex values.

Comment: It could be that the ? in a diamond symbol (`�`) is just what Explorer presents for a character it does not know how to print.  It is likely that Explorer shows characters in the default of the host OS, for Windows this may be 437 which is a ASCII character set and does not have knowledge of may of the higher value UTF characters.  If you did write it as STRING format, then the `Ü` may get converted from the UTF-16 character to the equivalent in ASCII assuming that character exists in the ASCII character set.

Comment: I just checked and found this in a google search "The replacement character (often a black diamond with a white question mark or an empty square box) is a symbol found in the Unicode standard at code point U+FFFD in the Specials table. It is used to indicate problems when a system is unable to render a stream of data to a correct symbol.".  I would guess that the data on the queue has distinct HEX codes representing the characters you put to the queue using CCSID 1200 (UTF-16), the default for .NET since you did a WriteBytes.

Comment: Explorer is displaying what it can, and for those it can not display you see the `�` symbol.  Likely your downstream app also does not expect the content of the message to be in UTF-16.  Are you sure the Format is `MQC.MQFMT_NONE`?  `amqsbcg` output will confirm this.

Comment: Any updates on this?  Were you able to view the message with amqsbcg?

Comment: Looking for updates on this. Was anyone able to resolve this issue? When I send something like "Andrew" to the queue I'm getting back "....A.n.d.r.e.w". I assume that this is a character set thing but I haven't been able to crack it. I am using writeString.

Comment: @SonBrooks For our issue, we actually had to use `WriteString` as after horrible documentation and dotPeeking the code the sender was using, they were writing and reading to the queue as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default MQ doesn't change the character set of your message. So by default it is the responsibility of the sending and receiving applications to agree and maintain a character set that suits both.

You can request MQ to do character set conversion either in the receiving application, when that calls a get, or on the sender channels when the message is transmitted between queue managers. But even if you request character set conversion from MQ, it is still the sending applications responsibility to actually write the data into the message using the character set the application is setting on the MQ message header.

Based on your code it seems your sending application doesn't use the correct character set when it writes the bytes to the message. If you use WriteBytes, you need to manually convert the string into bytes using the desired character set.

I'd suggest you to use the WriteString method, which is designed to use the chracter set specified in the CharacterSet property:

> The WriteString method converts from Unicode to the character set encoded in CharacterSet. If CharacterSet is set to its default value, MQC.MQCCSI_Q_MGR, which is 0, no conversion takes place and CharacterSet is set to 1200. If you set CharacterSet to some other value, WriteString converts from Unicode to the alternate value.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q111220_.htm

And by the way, for debugging character set issues you have to be very careful what tools you use to check the message, as your tool needs to be able to interpret the character set of the message. For example MQ Explorer uses the character set of your workstation where you run it, so it will show every message with that one character set, so is not suitable to debug these issues. The best is to get the message off the queue without asking the QM for conversion with rfhutil for example, save it to a file and look at it with a hex editor.